# Is there an ellipsis after main verb?

Tags: sentence-construction, ellipsis

> I do not know *that fact* how many years of life are before me.

Is marked term an ellipsis? Is there an defining attributive appositive clause started on how?

Comment: The sentence is not grammatical English so it is very difficult to answer your question. I suggest that you quote the passage within which it occurs so we can figure out what meaning is intended. My guess at the moment is "I do not know as a fact how many years ..."

Comment: This sentence was publihed in english book.

Comment: I asked you to quote the passage in which the sentence occurs, not argue with me about whether it is grammatical.

Comment: It's a direct speech on a book cover: "I,'m a grown man, I thought. I do not know how many years of life are before me. I cannot wait anymore. When I was going to school, I was preoccupied with good grades or getting cute girls to like me..."

Comment: So you've added something to the sentence you're asking about? That makes it hard, if not impossible, to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment by the original poster makes clear, the original question misstates the sentence being asked about. The actual sentence does not have "that fact" as the object of "know."

Subordinate clauses may act as nouns. In particular, subordinate clauses initiated by words that are also interrogatives ("who," "what," "where," "when," "why," and "how") frequently introduce clauses used as nouns.

> Why the cat fled from the mouse is a mystery.

The subject of the preceding sentence is the clause introduced by "why."

Such clauses are especially common as introducing clauses that are objects of verbs indicating degree of knowledge: "think," "suspect," "guess," "feel," "know," *etc.*

I hesitate to assert that such uses are ellipsis because they are so common and so idiomatic. But it is easy to interpret them as though there is an ellipsis.

> I do not know how many years of life are before me

means

> I do not know [the answer to the question asking] how many years of life are before me